# Почему идёт исключение non parseable string

Tags: c#, .net

```
class Program
{
    private static void Func(string UserInput)
    {
        string UserStringNum = UserInput.Replace(" ", "");
        string UserStringNumOut = Convert.ToInt32(UserStringNum, 2).ToString();
        char[] StrArray = UserStringNum.ToArray();
        string BackToStr;
        if (StrArray.Length % 2 == 0)
        {
            BackToStr = StrArray.ToString() + "00";
        }
        else
        {
            BackToStr = StrArray.ToString() + "11";
        }
        int Output = Convert.ToInt32(BackToStr, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(Output);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string UserIn =  Console.ReadLine();
        Func(UserIn);
    }
}
```

Я относительно долго искал ответ на свой вопрос и у себя в голове и немного в гугле, но почему при таком написании кода мне выдаёт эксэпшн, на то что у меня есть строка, которую нельзя распарсить? Может я просто не очень одарённый и проблема легко решается? В общем узнаю из ответа.

Comment: А в чём задача то заключается, что делает этот код? Что вводите, что надо вывести?

Comment: Мне нужно получить итоговую строку Output, которая создаётся из вводимого числа - UserInput. Там я перевожу его в двоичную строку, добовляю к ней числа и потом перевожу обратно в десятичное число.

Comment: Вы не переводите в двоичную строку, вы двоичную строку парсите в число, затем делаете десятичную строку. А надо как? Задачу расскажите нормально.

Comment: Нужно сделать с десятеричным числом на входе ряд преобразований, а именно перевести его в двоичное, затем добавить к двоичному представлению или "00", или "11" в зависимости от того, чётное ли число на входе., после вывести десятеричное представление изменённого двоичного числа. Не знаю, как описать задачу лучше.

Comment: Возмите на заметку на будущее `char[].ToString()` не делает из массива символов строку с этими символами, чтобы сделать строку из массива символов, надо `new string(char[])` сделать. Проверьте с выводом в консоль, как это работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> перевести его в двоичное, затем добавить к двоичному представлению или "00", или "11" в зависимости от того, чётное ли число на входе., после вывести десятеричное представление изменённого двоичного числа

Вы перемудрили, решается действительно просто

```
private static void Func(string input)
{
    int number = int.Parse(input.Trim()); // Trim убирает пробелы по краям
    if (number % 2 == 0)
    {
        number = number * 4; // сдвиг двоичного представления на 2 разряда влево
    }
    else
    {
        number = number * 4 + 3; // 3 это 11 в двоичном представлении
    }
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Вот и весь код

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, милый сударь. Проблема решена и я теперь понимаю как. А так же спасибо за эти комментарии в коде. <3 Удачи вам, вы сделали мой день.